# How do I get SlowCheetah to use my web config transforms when debugging locally?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, slowcheetah

I read that SlowCheetah can do this. I've installed the extension and the nuget package in my project, created a new build configuration ("Debugging with UAT db"), created a transform (replaces connection string with UAT connection string) and tested it via Preview Transform, however it does not apply the transform when I run locally. I cannot find any settings to make it do this.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (VS2017), and ended up in a (not so pretty) workaround....

Structure:

[image]

I let the Web.config hold all the settings for belonging to Web.Debug.Config, 
and only let Web.Release.config and Web.Test.Config hold transformations.

Hence, Web.Debug.Config holds no transformations - it only holds the content it had initailly.

When I publish Release and Test to other destinations, the transformations are done correctly, and when I debug locally ("F5") from visual studio, no transformations take place, and all the settings from the Web.config are applied.

If someone comes up with a better way, PLEASE share :)